# How to generate all strings and all ++ ,- - numbers against java input file and also mention this is string or single alphabet?

Tags: java

I'm working on a java scanner project.The scanner will then scan the code file and identifies all the tokens and list them as the output for user. In case of an invalid token, Scanner should mention that a given token is invalid.
Here is my code

```
    try {                                         
        FileReader fin = null;
        try {
            fin = new FileReader(jTextField1.getText());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(fin);
        String line = null;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {



    // Get ending position

            System.out.println(line);


            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz[ =-+++--';().*{}[],!@#$%^&/]", true);


            int caret=jTextArea1.getCaretPosition();

              while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
               switch(st.nextToken()){ 
                  case "++":
              jTextArea1.insert("++"+" "+":Unary Operator "+"\n",caret);
                          break;
                          case "--":
              jTextArea1.insert("--"+" "+":Unary Operator "+"\n",caret);
                              break;
                              case "!":
              jTextArea1.insert("!"+" "+":Unary Operator "+"\n",caret);
                                  break;
                                  case "+":
              jTextArea1.insert("+"+" "+":Airthmatic Operator "+"\n",caret);
                                      break;
                                case "-":
              jTextArea1.insert("-"+" "+":Airthmatic Operator "+"\n",caret);
                                    break;
                                    case "*":
              jTextArea1.insert("*"+" "+":Airthmatic Operator "+"\n",caret);
                                      break;
                                case "/":
              jTextArea1.insert("/"+" "+":Airthmatic Operator "+"\n",caret);
                                    break;
                                    case "%":
              jTextArea1.insert("%"+" "+":Airthmatic Operator "+"\n",caret);
                                    break;
                                        case "<<":
              jTextArea1.insert("<<"+" "+":Rational Operator "+"\n",caret);
                                      break;
                                case ">>":
              jTextArea1.insert(">>"+" "+":Rational Operator "+"\n",caret);
                                    break;

                                        case "=":
              jTextArea1.insert("="+" "+":Rational Operator "+"\n",caret);
                                      break;
                                case "(":
              jTextArea1.insert("("+" "+":Symbol "+"\n",caret);
                                    break;
                                    case "&":
              jTextArea1.insert("&"+" "+":Conditional Operator "+"\n",caret);
                                    break;
                                    case "|":
              jTextArea1.insert("|"+" "+":Conditional Operator "+"\n",caret);
                                    break;
                                        case ")":
              jTextArea1.insert(")"+" "+":Symbol "+"\n",caret);
                                            break;
                                            case "{":
              jTextArea1.insert("{"+" "+":Symbol "+"\n",caret);
                                                break;
                                                case "}":
              jTextArea1.insert("}"+" "+":Symbol "+"\n",caret);
                                                    break;
                                            case "[":
              jTextArea1.insert("["+" "+":Symbol "+"\n",caret);
                                                break;
                                                case "]":
              jTextArea1.insert("]"+" "+":Symbol "+"\n",caret);
                                                    break;
                                                    case ".":
              jTextArea1.insert("."+" "+":Symbol "+"\n",caret);
                                                break;
                                                case ",":
              jTextArea1.insert(","+" "+":Symbol "+"\n",caret);
                                                    break;
                                                    case ";":
              jTextArea1.insert(";"+" "+":Symbol "+"\n",caret);
                                                break;
                                                case ":":
              jTextArea1.insert(":"+" "+":Symbol "+"\n",caret);
                                                    break;
                                                    case "'":
              jTextArea1.insert("'"+" "+":Symbol "+"\n",caret);
                                                break;


                                default :
                                    break;
```

here is my output http://s11.postimg.org/962xs85r7/Untitled.jpg
program output works for all brackets and operators as i mention in switch statement,but i want that is show all the strings as shown in the output and also mention it is string and also ++,-- numbers,but How can i use string check and ++,-- numbers in switch statement.For example: system : string  ab :string and same as all strings shown in output,Thanks

Comment: Try clarifying the question,  at least I don't understand what you are actually asking... Especially the "for example" piece of code(?) at the end of the question, format it properly, it might be the key.

Comment: But if I understand correctly, you can't. Use `if` instead (possibly in the `default:` part of `switch`).

Comment: I m asking that "How can i generate all the strings and ++,-- numbers which is in the java input file". i want this kind of output :if file contains system.out.println then system :String   . :operator out:string   println:string

Comment: if file contains ++,--numbers then also shown ++ :unary operators  --:unary operators @hyde

Comment: @hyde my code working fine for all brackets and +,-,. and all other shown in output,but i want for strings and ++,--numbers

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you cannot use a regex in a switch statement.
What you can do is use the default. In the default you can add this sort of code: 
if (str.matches("[A-Za-z]"))

To use the string you need to save it ahead when using nextToken():
String str = st.nextToken();

The regex may vary according to your assumptions

Comment: How can i use this  if (str.matches("[A-Za-z]")){
                                       jTextArea1.insert()
                                       
                                   }    I want this type of output shown stringhere :string

Comment: default:    
                                   if (str.matches("[A-Za-z]")){
                                       jTextArea1.insert("string",caret);
                                        } i use this but it generate strange output all string shown in a single line stringstringstring

Comment: i use this in switch statement in end   default:    
                                   if (str.matches("[A-Za-z]")){
                                        jTextArea1.insert("[A-Za-Z]"+" "+":String "+"\n",caret);
                                       break;
                                   } here is my output http://s22.postimg.org/z3uz6tuvl/Untitled.jpg